# Do skill bonuses stack?

Tags: stacking, wfrp-2e, warhammer, wfrp

Are skill bonuses always cumulative?

- If I have an item giving me +10% Charm and another item giving me +20% Charm, do I now have +30% Charm, or do I just take the highest bonus?
- Likewise, if I have two Talents that each give a +10% bonus to the same Skill, would I have a +20% bonus overall?
- Lastly, do combat bonuses stack? For example, if I am outnumbered 3-to-1 (+20%) *and* my opponent uses a Half-Action to Aim (+10%) would my opponent get a +30% to their next attack against me?

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! Be sure to take the [tour]! This question seems well written, but it might invite better answers if you could list the specific Skills/Talents giving you trouble. The general rule may not apply to your specific use case. Thanks for posting!

Comment: It's not so much a specific skill/talent that is in question. My group has been operating under the assumption that in any circumstance that the highest showing bonus was the only one that applied. It has recently come to our attention that the book never explicitly says that and other people have told me that all bonuses should apply. I was just hoping someone with more knowledge of the system could clarify for me and our GM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Generally, Yes

The most common source of permanent bonuses to your Skills will be through Career Advances. It costs 100 XP to advance a Skill by 10% (WFRP Core Rulebook, Page 27). Advancing a skill in this way will always further your bonus - from 10% to 20%, 20% to 30%, etc. - but the advance can only be taken if it is a skill your career has access to. In other words, getting the +20% requires Exiting your Career into a second Career that has the same Skill available as an Advance.

Talents provide bonuses in specific instances and are meant to represent areas of expertise for a given character. For example, if you have Etiquette (+10% to Charm while dealing with nobility) and Schemer (+10% to intrigue-related Charm tests) your character would receive the benefits of both Talents while dealing with intrigue specific to Nobles.

In Combat all bonuses are cumulative unless otherwise stated. In your example the bonuses do stack, as long as the Opponent attacks with a Standard Attack (since Aim only applies a +10% to your next Standard Attack). A handy thing to pay attention to: specific Actions that grant bonuses (like Aim, Guarded Attack, and All Out Attack) will list the circumstances under which they provide those bonuses. Aim does not stack with All Out Attack because All Out Attack is not a Standard Attack. Similarly, two Attacks will not stack because only one Attack can be made in a turn (So you cannot Charge Attack and then Standard Attack, even if you have been buffed with Stag's Leap).

### For Magic Items, Maybe

Magic Items in Warhammer Fantasy are as powerful and coveted as they are rare and mysterious. Bonuses provided by these powerful artifacts *does* stack with bonuses your character has earned through Advances.

If you are fortunate enough to come across two Magic Items that grant a bonus to the same skill *AND* your party agrees that you should be allowed to have both, it is technically true that the bonuses would stack, however this could lead to a scenario where your Skill bonus reaches a ridiculous level.

As far as I know, there is no official ruling on the stacking of Magic Item bonuses (possibly because the writers did not expect such an unlikely scenario to come to pass) but my group has always deferred to the GM's best judgement in such cases.

Again, these instances are very rare; on one occasion requiring careful coordination between two players taking advantage of the fact that our GM wanted each player to have access to a "custom" Magic Item - both players requested Magic Items with similar properties and would allow the other to *borrow* the item essentially doubling all of the bonuses. The GM eventually ruled that the bonuses wouldn't stack for that instance since it was clear the two players were intentionally gaming the system.

Comment: When it comes to skill bonuses I don't count that as part of the question, so sorry if that was misleading. I suppose a better example would be in order...  
Say I was trying to play politics to a group of Nobles...   
  
I have a Charm of 52  
I have the Talent Etiquette for a bonus +10% when Charming Nobles  
I also have the Talent Schemer for a bonus +10% for Intrigue related Charm tests  
Lets say I also had a situation bonus that gave me a +20% (for the sake of example)    

Would my roll be at a +20% (as the highest showing bonus) or +40% ( the added total of all the bonuses)?

Comment: @Raktus, this is why I was asking for a more specific example in my comment up top. I will revise my answer to address Talents.

Comment: Well, as I said, it's a question about if *all* types of bonuses stack, not just talents. I could give the same example in the case of an opponent that is outnumbered 3-1 AND prone. Two different bonuses, do they add up or do you take the highest of the two. I'm interested in both answers equally... I was just hoping that they were the same answer. Sorry if it was confusing. >.< @GreedyRadish